# How to prevent certain items in VStack from being clipped?

Tags: swift, swiftui

If I have a `VStack` with limited height and the contents of the `VStack` require more height than what's available, is there a way I can control which items get clipped?

I created the short sample below to illustrate.

I'd like "Bottom" to be clipped instead of the black rectangle when the toggle is set to "Open".

I've tried `.fixedSize`, `.layoutPriority` and a number of other things.

[image]

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isOpen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        container
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder var container: some View {
        VStack {
            header
            content
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 110)
        .background(.gray)
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder var header: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 10)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder var content: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Picker("mypicker", selection: $isOpen) {
                Text("Open").tag(true)
                Text("Closed").tag(false)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            if isOpen {
                Text("Top")
                Text("Middle")
                Text("Bottom")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would separate layout of header and content (assuming requirement that header should be visible always) independently of what's really in header or content

It can be done using free space consumer (like Color) and overlay

```
@ViewBuilder var container: some View {
    VStack {
        header
        Color.clear
            .overlay(content)   // << here !!
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 110, alignment: .top)
    .background(.gray)
    .cornerRadius(20)
}
```

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: While this seems promising, and apparently works in this simplified example, I tried it and it doesn't work in my full use case. Probably because the `content` is more complicated than just three texts. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.opacity` instead, so that your `VStack` saves spaces in advance without messing up your layouts later. Code is below the image:

[image]

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var isOpen: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    container
}
@ViewBuilder var container: some View {
    VStack {
        header
        content
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 110)
    .background(.gray)
    .cornerRadius(20)
}

@ViewBuilder var header: some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 10)
        .padding(.top)
}
@ViewBuilder var content: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Picker("mypicker", selection: $isOpen) {
            Text("Open").tag(true)
            Text("Closed").tag(false)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        Group {
            Text("Top")
            Text("Middle")
            Text("Bottom")
        }
        .opacity(isOpen ? 1 : 0) //here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately wouldn't work for my use case as `content` is external and not something we have control over.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when my container's size is smaller than its content, I will think about using a ScrollView. It guarantees user can see everything.

```
@ViewBuilder var container: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            header
            content
        }.pading()
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 110)
    .background(.gray)
    .cornerRadius(20)
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I considered ScrollView but that doesn't work for my use case, 1) because header can't be within the scroll view, 2) the content itself contains another scroll view which causes more problems. Sorry for leaving these details out. I wanted to keep the original question brief and approachable.